# jQuery terminology regarding callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, terminology

```
$('#foo').click(function(){  });
```

Is `function(){  }` an anonymous function, or a self-invoking function? And what would be the difference between the two?

Comment: it definitely _is_ an anonymous function, but I'm very curious about what a self-invoking function looks like.

Comment: @11684 Guess we both learned something today then ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function with no name / reference is called as anonymous function. The function inside `$('#foo').click(function(){  });` is an anonymous function.

Self-invoking function is a function that is called right after it definition.

`(function () { })();` -> is a self-invoking function.

Comment: Ok, what made me confused was that the anonymous function is called automatically inside the click event. Thanks for clearing it out for me

Comment: But it's not called immediately, it's called by the click event handler. The self-invoking function is called immediately.

Comment: I saw two versions of a self-invoking function here, could anyone tell me which is correct/what the difference is? Version 1: 
`( function () {} ) ();`, Version 2: `( function () {} () )`.

Comment: @11684 six and a half years later, I can tell you that....there is no difference. It's mostly a stylistic choice which one you choose but the two are equivalent in terms of functionality. The key is that `function () {}` when placed inside the brackets will be interpreted as an *expression* and you need *an expression* in order to invoke it. Whether you place the invocation `()` inside or outside you get the same effect. It's sort of similar to how `(2 + 3)` and `(2) + 3` will have the same result.

Answer (score 5):

That's an anonymous function.

A "self-invoking function" is, as the name suggests, a function that invokes itself.

Like this:

```
(function(){
    console.log('hi');
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an anonymous function.  I don't know what you mean by 'self invoking function', maybe this:

```
(function(){alert("hello")}())
```

That is an anonymous function that you define and then immediately invoke--the parentheses following the function are what cause the function to execute.

In the first case, you are creating a function that you want javascript to execute at some time in the future, i.e. when the html element is clicked.  js stores the function somewhere, and then when the html is clicked, js invokes the function.

So the difference is that one function executes NOW, and one function executes LATER.

Answer (score 0):

A self-invoking function is equivalent to:

```
function self_invoke(params...) {...};
function(args...);
```

The use of the anonymous function is equivalent to:

```
function anonymous(params...) {...};
$('#foo').click(anonymous);
```

In both cases, the difference is that the namespace is not polluted with a name for the little function.